# gitignore only user contents and temporary files

Tags: ce-1.8.1.0, git

There are some sample `.gitignore` files on web [+](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/programming-magento/git-ignore-gitignore-file-for-magento-project/), [+](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Magento.gitignore) for magento projects, but I want only ignore user contents and cache files, here is my current `.gitignore`:

```
/var/  # for temporary files
/media/ # for user contents
```

Now I would like is it enough?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this should be sufficient to ignore all user added content and import/export/cache/session/reporting files.  Obviously you can add to this as per your examples should you wish in order to ignore more.